# Deleting list element after use

Tags: python, algorithm

```
s = []
seats = [4,1,5,9]
students = [1,3,2,6]
for i in range(len(students)):
    s.append((min(seats, key=lambda x:abs(x-students[i]))))
print(s)
```

Returns minimum distance for each of our student values. I want to delete the seat from use after a student is allocated it. How would I perform that?

Comment: Have you thought about using a set instead of a list?

Comment: What is the overall task?

Answer (score 2):

Use `list.remove` with the last value of `s`

```
for i in range(len(students)):
    s.append(min(seats, key=lambda x: abs(x - students[i])))
    seats.remove(s[-1])
```

Comment: This works for the data given in the OP's question. Change *students* to [1,3,2,3] for example and it will not produce the correct result. This is because the list *s* would be [1,4,1,4] and after the *remove()* would become [1,1,4]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the last item from a list I can think of two ways:

1)

```
mylist = mylist[:-1]
```

This is fine even if the original list is empty. However, it does mean that a new copy of the list has to be created and that could have a negative impact on memory usage.

2)

```
if mylist:
  mylist.pop(-1)
```

This will remove the last entry in the list *in situ*. You do however need to check to ensure that there is at least something in the list

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```py
seats = set([4,1,5,9])
students = [1,3,2,6]

result = []
for student in students:
    seat = min(seats, key=lambda seat:abs(seat-student))
    seats.remove(seat)
    result.append(seat)

print(result)
```